# Как наложить картинку на картинку ?

Tags: php

Как наложить картинку на картинку посредством php, css или javascript ? Плюс сохранить все это безобразие в одном изображении(слое) формате png.

Comment: Вам нужен только PHP. JS и CSS  в вашем случае не помогут.

Comment: Каким именно способом можно это сделать ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Наложение водяного знака](http://www.sdws.ru/topic.php?t=4&id=30)